# No such file or directory error when running pyspark

Tags: apache-spark

I installed spark but when I run `pyspark` on the terminal, I get

```
/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.4.5_1/libexec/bin/pyspark: line 24: /Users/miguel/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/load-spark-env.sh: No such file or directory
/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.4.5_1/libexec/bin/pyspark: line 77: /Users/miguel/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-submit: No such file or directory
/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.4.5_1/libexec/bin/pyspark: line 77: exec: /Users/miguel/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-submit: cannot execute: No such file or directory
```

I've tried uninstalling and installing again (spark, java, scala) but it keeps throwing this error. Have also searched on here and on GitHub issues but couldn't find anything that worked.

Additional info:

`brew doctor`

```
(myenv) C02YH1U3FSERT:~ miguel$ brew doctor
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry or file an issue; just ignore this. Thanks!

Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and which additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew-provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:
  /Users/miguel/.pyenv/shims/python3.7-config
  /Users/miguel/.pyenv/shims/python3.7m-config
  /Users/miguel/.pyenv/shims/python-config
  /Users/miguel/.pyenv/shims/python3-config
```

`brew tap`

```
(myenv) C02YH1U3FSERT:~ miguel$ brew tap
adoptopenjdk/openjdk
homebrew/cask
homebrew/cask-versions
homebrew/core
```

`hadoop version`

```
Hadoop 3.2.1
Source code repository https://gitbox.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop.git -r b3cbbb467e22ea829b3808f4b7b01d07e0bf3842
Compiled by rohithsharmaks on 2019-09-10T15:56Z
Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
From source with checksum 776eaf9eee9c0ffc370bcbc1888737
This command was run using /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.2.1_1/libexec/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-3.2.1.jar
```

`echo $SPARK_HOME`

```
/Users/miguel/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7
```

`hdfs dfs -ls`

```
WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Found 6 items
...
```

I've spent quite some time on this, if anyone can point to the solution would be great.

Comment: This seems like improperly set up Hadoop. Can you run anything on Hadoop? `ls` would suffice.

Comment: I added the output of `hadoop version` above

Comment: `spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7` vs `apache-spark/2.4.5_1/libexec` vs `Hadoop 3.2.1`
I think you are facing quite the version incompatibilities. Based on what have you chosen these versions?

BTW this still doesn't show if at least Hadoop runs well. Try for example `hdfs dfs -ls /`.  

Are you running pyspark from `/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.4.5_1/libexec/bin/pyspark` while having `/Users/miguel/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7` as `SPARK_HOME` env variable?

Comment: Added all that info to the post. It seems you're right about the `SPARK_HOME`. I followed instructions on a tutorial online to install Spark.

Comment: I think your spark home is `/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.4.5_1/libexec` or run pyspark from /Users/miguel/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7`

Comment: Not sure I get what you mean... My `env` says `SPARK_HOME=/Users/miguel.carvalho/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7`

Comment: Try setting your $SPARK_HOME to `/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.4.5_1/libexec`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208485/discussion-between-mcansado-and-sasa-zejnilovic).

Answer (score 15):

The cause is because the SPARK_HOME is still set to the old path.
Even with `source ~/.bash_profile` this value didn't get unset, until I have applied:

```
unset SPARK_HOME
```

Then the errors went away.

Comment: I just changed my `SPARK_HOME` variable to the correct path and `source`d it again