# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/user/myname/spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2/./bin/spark-submit

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Whenever I ran `spark-shell` I am getting the following errors

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/user/myName/spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2/./bin/spark-submit`

My bash settings

```bash
export SPARK_HOME=/home/user/Myname/spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2
export PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS="--master local[2] pyspark-shell"
export PATH=$PATH:$SPARK_HOME/bin
```

Comment: Can you provide the content of those directories? Is the "spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2/bin/" directory missing, or does the file "spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2/bin/spark-submit" missing?

Comment: Itis all exists in the bin folder
beeline
beeline.cmd
docker-image-tool.sh
find-spark-home
find-spark-home.cmd
load-spark-env.cmd
load-spark-env.sh
pyspark
pyspark.cmd
pyspark2.cmd
run-example
run-example.cmd
spark-class
spark-class.cmd
spark-class2.cmd
spark-shell
spark-shell.cmd
spark-shell2.cmd
spark-sql
spark-sql.cmd
spark-sql2.cmd
spark-submit
spark-submit.cmd
spark-submit2.cmd
sparkR
sparkR.cmd
sparkR2.cmd

Comment: Wait-so if you do "cat /home/user/myName/spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2/./bin/spark-submit", the file exists? Or not? What exists in the bin folder seems contradict the FileNotFoundError message.

Comment: When I do cat I get cat: /home/user/myName/spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2/./bin/spark-submit: No such file or directory. But I go to that folder manually I see all the files. Also. I just realize there is a /./ between spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2/./bin/ but the manual folder structure is spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2/bin/. Not sure where that other layer came from.

Comment: Are you sure you are replacing "/user/myName/" with your user directory correctly? Also, what is the output of "ls /home/user/myName/spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2/./bin/"?

Comment: Yes, replacing correctly. and with ls the output is same as "No such file or directory"

Comment: @user1280483 Thanks for looking into it. The issue is resolved by the following commands.

1. unset SPARK_HOME === Found here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60390235/no-such-file-or-directory-error-when-running-pyspark

2. export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home"